# MySQL insert multiple row select in other table

Tags: mysql

I have small database with couple of tables for some small PHP project. One of my SELECTs (given bellow table) gives result like this:

+-------+------+------+
| idpart |  qty  |IMEI |
+-------+------+------+
| 2           | 4      |  xxx  |
| 6           | 1      | yyyy |
| 8           | 2      | zzzz |
|10         | 3      | ssss |
+-------+------+------+

Number of rows changes it can be 1 or n, but its never less then 1. idpart is not repeating it self as result of this query - it can be show only once. This is the actual query:

```
select odel_part.idpart as idpart, model_part.qtyused as qty, reparationorders.IMEI as IMEI
from reparation orders
inner join order model on order_model.idreparationorder=reparationorders.idreparationorder
inner join models on order_model.idmodel = models.idmodel
inner join model_part on models.idmodel = model_part.idmodel 
inner join parts on model_part.idpart = parts.idpart
where reparationorders.idreparationorder = 1
```

Result of this query along with some additional data which is fixed **has to be inserted in to other table**. Other table has following fields: 
+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
|  idtrans  |  idpart   |  qty   |  date  |  tt   | IMEI |
+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+-----+-------+

**idtrans** - int which autoincrements
**idpart** - from query (*idpart*)
**qty** - from query (*qty*)
**date** - entered manualy
**tt** - entered manualy
**IMEI** - from query (*IMEI*)

in this 2nd table idtrans is unique, idpart can repeat it self thorough rows (this is intended behaviour, because this table will track usage of this parts for different dates).
Can you help me with doing this insert to 2nd table (name of 2nd table is transactions)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would just do:

```
insert into transactions(idpart, qty, date, tt, IMEI)
    select idpart, qty, now(), @tt, imei
    from reparations orders . . .;
```

The `. . .` is just the rest of your query.  I am guessing that you want the current date/time inserted for "date"; `now()` provides that information.